# How can I use cursors to paginate field-expanded queries?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-field-expansion

I can do this:

`/<post_id>/comments?filter=stream&limit=100&after=<cursor>`

But this doesn't work:

`/<post_id>?fields=comments.filter(stream).limit(100).after(<cursor>)`

Am I missing something in the syntax? Though cursor-based paging and field expansion were launched a the same time, their respective docs don't reflect each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out (I think).

Most cursors have an `=` (equals sign) appended to them. For example: `MzA=`

This causes this syntax error in field expansion:

`Syntax error "Expected ")" instead of '".' at character 79: comments.filter(stream).limit(10).summary(true).fields(id,like_count).after(NDA"`

However, stripping the trailing `=` resolves the syntax error and results seem to paginate as expected.